# Eclipse Demandware server connection not uploading

Tags: eclipse, salesforce, demandware

I got a new version of Eclipse Oxygen and installed the following Demandware plugin: http://developer.salesforce.com/media/commercecloud/uxstudio/4.6

I have imported my cartridges into the work space, and setup a new digital server connection with my sandbox, however when ever I try to upload the cartridges to my sandbox nothing happens.

Could I be missing a set somewhere?

Comment: After giving up on Oxygen, I download Eclipse Mars and installed version 4.5 of the salesforce uxstudio, and everything worked right away. Cant explain why.

Answer (score 2):

You should add your cartridges to project references. Please, use your project's **Properties** context menu. There you'll find **Project References** tab where you can add needed cartridges to upload to the sandbox